# timing of mineral consumption, and absorption competition

Tags: minerals, iron-supplements

It makes sense that many minerals inhibit the absorption of other minerals because they are chemically similar and therefore often compete for similar biochemical pathways for absorption [e.g. iron, magnesium, zinc, etc. are divalent cations].

1. If the human body absorbed several times the RDA of each of those nutrients [e.g. iron, copper, zinc, magnesium, calcium, selenium, manganese, cobalt, etc., all the usual suspects], but still in the same proportion as the RDA's of those minerals so that they remained "balanced", would regular elevated consumption of the above mentioned minerals be likely to cause health problems to the average human body?
2. In order to not have absorption issues of competition between minerals, how long does the average human body need between supplements of a given nutrient before supplementation with the next nutrient can take place without absorption problems? [e.g. 2 hours, 3 hours, 5 hours?]